# creating primary key on two columns which are unique together

Tags: mysql

Apologies if this question is a silly question. I'm trying to avoid creating an arbitrary index column as the primary key. What I'd like to do is the following:

Create a primary key based on the uniqueness of the student_id + section_id columns (neither individually will be unique in the table, but the two together will be). The following does not work, but I'm wondering if there is something similar that would?

```
CREATE TABLE Registration 
    (
        student_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        section_id VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL,
        midterm_grade VARCHAR(2), 
        final_grade VARCHAR(2),

        CONSTRAINT Registration_unique UNIQUE (student_id, section_id),
        CONSTRAINT Registration_pk PRIMARY KEY (Registration_unique),

        CONSTRAINT Registration_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES Student(student_id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT Registration_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (section_id) REFERENCES Section(section_id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
    )
    ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `UNIQUE` because you can make a composite `PRIMARY KEY (student_id, section_id)`.

```
CREATE TABLE Registration 
    (
        student_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        section_id VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL,
        midterm_grade VARCHAR(2), 
        final_grade VARCHAR(2),

        CONSTRAINT Registration_pk PRIMARY KEY (student_id, section_id),

        CONSTRAINT Registration_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES Student(student_id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT Registration_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (section_id) REFERENCES Section(section_id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
    )
```

If you want that `student_id` will be unique and `section_id` will be unique you need to make two unique keys

```
CREATE TABLE Registration 
    (
        student_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        section_id VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL,
        midterm_grade VARCHAR(2), 
        final_grade VARCHAR(2),
        CONSTRAINT Registration_unique_student_id UNIQUE (student_id),
        CONSTRAINT Registration_unique_section_id UNIQUE (section_id),
        CONSTRAINT Registration_pk PRIMARY KEY (student_id, section_id),

        CONSTRAINT Registration_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES Student(student_id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT Registration_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (section_id) REFERENCES Section(section_id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
    )
```

It means you can insert only rows of type `One student - One section` and `One section - One student`.

If you want to use the same sections for several students then delete the second unique `CONSTRAINT Registration_unique_section_id UNIQUE (section_id)`.

Comment: I tried that originally, but there are duplicate values in student_id and duplicate values in section_id. Combined, each instance of student_id and section_id will be unique, but individually they are not.

As a result, I believe, I got the following error:

     ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '96052' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY` can contain only unique combinations. For example - (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,3)

Comment: so for the following records:

('112', '103', 'A', 'A') and ('112', '104', 'B', 'A'), and the primary key is created on the first two columns, I shouldn't get an error?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Do you want it? `One student - One section` and `One section - One student`.

Comment: I see that I am not supposed to post "thank you", but as this is my first post, I think I should get a pass. 

I had an error in one of the parent table which was causing the error.

As I've begun teaching myself a couple programming languages and snooping around stackoverflow, I have been thoroughly impressed with sites such as this and people such as yourself which share information so freely. Much appreciated--problem solved and I now better understand composite keys.